# awk regex example

Tags: linux, awk

Input format :

```
"130234":"f",
"130235":"m",
"130236":"f",
"130237":"f",
```

I want convert the above input from file to below output using awk command. 
1. truncate the last "," and enclose with curly brace. Can any one help me on this.

```
{"130234":"f",
"130235":"m",
"130236":"f",
"130237":"f"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "{"}{if (a) print a; a=$0}END{sub(/,$/, "}");print}' file
{"130234":"f",
"130235":"m",
"130236":"f",
"130237":"f"}
```

Comment: or `gawk -v RS="^$" '{sub(/^/,"{");sub(/,\n$/,"}")}1' file` `:P`.

Comment: Thanks! works as expected. But instead of printing how can i write this to file.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{printf "{"}{if (a) print a; a=$0}END{sub(/,$/, "}");print}' infile > outfile`

Comment: I am a complete new bee to this. This works! Thanks @avinash.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `sed` for such trivial substitution:

```
$ sed '1s/^/{/;$s/,$/}/' file
{"130234":"f",
"130235":"m",
"130236":"f",
"130237":"f"}
```